# what is the torque difference in single plate clutch disks and multidisk clutches?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, applied-mechanics

I have a review question that I am not sure about the answer. The question goes like this:

"In comparison to single plate clutches, multidisk clutches are associated to which of the below notions?"

a) Linearly increased torque from identical axis force

b) Exponentially increased torque from linearly increased axial force

c) Exponentially increased torque from identical axial force

Comment: Total torque is shared over more surface area. Think about it.

Comment: This looks like  a homework exercise. Please provide your thoughts on this, so that people can help you improve your engineering thinking skills (and not just get you a pass mark)

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.